# Setting global variable to rewrite some url - .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Perhaps it will appear quite easy but I have an issue with my .htaccess. I want to rewrite my url such that `<a href="/admin">some text</a>` can be rewritten as `<a href=""http://localhost:8888/madison/the-madison-project/admin/index">some text</a>`

So I set this :

```
SetEnv root:/madison/the-madison-project/
RewriteRule ^admin[/]?$ {%ENV:root}admin/index
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Edit : after several attempts, it is perhaps simpler I post my whole .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
ExpiresActive On

#Expire Header
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "now plus 7 days"
</FilesMatch>

ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 7 days"
ExpiresDefault "now plus 7 days"

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css

SetEnv root:/madison/the-madison-project/
#SetEnvIf Request_URI ^ root=/madison/the-madison-project/
#RewriteRule ^ - [E=root:/madison/the-madison-project/]

RewriteRule ^(assets|inc) - [L]

RewriteRule ^admin[/]?$                         %{ENV:root}admin/index

RewriteRule ^admin/edit/(.*)$                   %{ENV:root}index.php?type=admin&action=edit&page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$                        %{ENV:root}index.php?type=admin&action=view&page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^login$                             index.php?action=view&type=login&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^forgot-password$                   index.php?action=view&type=forgot-password&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^edit/user(/)?$                     index.php?action=edit&type=user&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^signup(/)?$                        index.php?action=edit&type=user&id=0&%1  [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)(/)?                  index.php?action=view&type=note&user=$1&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(suggestion|comment)/([0-9]+)(/)?  index.php?action=view&type=note&page=open&note_type=$1&note=$2&%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]+)/(suggestion|comment)/([0-9]+)(/)?    index.php?action=view&type=note&page=$1&note_type=$2&note=$3&%1 [L]

#Catch All Pages
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]+)(/)?          %{ENV:root}index.php?action=view&type=page&page=$1&%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv)

- variable and value are separated by white space instead of a colon
- **Note**

> The internal environment variables set by this directive are set after most early request processing directives are run, such as access control and URI-to-filename mapping. If the environment variable you're setting is meant as input into this early phase of processing such as the RewriteRule directive, you should instead set the environment variable with [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#%20setenvif).
>   
>   This would be for example

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^ root=/madison/the-madison-project/
```

Alternatively, you can use a non rewriting rule, to set the environment variable

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=root:/madison/the-madison-project/]
```

And finally, you must put the percent sign `%` in front of the curly braces

```
RewriteRule ^admin[/]?$ %{ENV:root}admin/index
```

**PS**: As you can see, there are at least three forms of separating environment variables from their values

- white space
  [`SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) **var value**
- equal sign (assignment)
  [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) condition **var=value**
- colon
  `RewriteRule` pattern substitution [`[E=var:value]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e)

Comment: @user1611830 I hadn't looked at the `SetEnv` properly. Please see updated answer.